# Composer install Symfont PHP version error

Tags: php, laravel-6.2

Hey guys I just pulled a project from bitbucket and tried running `composer install` I got the following error

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for symfony/css-selector v5.0.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v5.0.4].
>       - symfony/css-selector v5.0.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     Problem 2

So I updated my PHP version from 7.2.4 to 7.4.4, stopped the wamp server then shut down my system and restarted it. Checked my server configuration and can confirm that the php version updated successfully

```
 Server Configuration

Apache Version:
    2.4.33  - Documentation
PHP Version:
    7.4.4  - Documentation
Server Software:
    Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/7.4.4RC1 - Port defined for Apache: 80
```

Tried running the `composer install` again and still getting the same error.

The project is running Laravel 6.2 as seen in the composer.json file `"laravel/framework": "^6.2",`

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to check our environment variables. Take a look here : https://www.forevolve.com/en/articles/2016/10/27/how-to-add-your-php-runtime-directory-to-your-windows-10-path-environment-variable/ . And change the path of the PHP exe to the 7.4 version.

Comment: @VincentDecaux Do I need to remove the one for 7.2? I also think I need to restart the system after adding the variable for 7.4.4, right?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the application running on my dev server by doing the following

1. Select PHP 7.4.4 from wamp PHP list
2. Run `composer update`
3. Run `composer install`